# regex: combine capturing group with OR condition

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string :

```
s = "id_john, num847, id_000, num___"
```

I know how to retrieve either of 2 patterns with `|`:

```
re.findall("id_[a-z]+|num[0-9]+", s)
#### ['id_john', 'num847'] # OK
```

I know how to capture a portion only of a match with parenthesis:

```
re.findall("id_([a-z]+)", s)
#### ['john']
```

But I fail when i try to combine those two features, this is my **desired output**:

```
#### ['john', '847']
```

Thanks for your help.. (I work with python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for lookaheads or complex patterns.

Consider this:

```
>>> re.findall('id_([a-z]+)|num([0-9]+)', s)
[('john', ''), ('', '847')]
```

When the first pattern matches, the first group will contain the match, and the second group will be empty. When the second pattern matches, the first group is empty, and the second group contains the match.

Since one of the two groups will always be empty, joining them couldn't hurt.

```
>>> [a+b for a,b in re.findall('id_([a-z]+)|num([0-9]+)', s)]
['john', '847']
```

Comment: thanks, i had indeed this first output when i tried and i was confused. thank you for the "post treatment"

Comment: @agenis: Added an explanation of the tricky groups arrangement ;)

Comment: sorry, but still i don(t get it why this second emtpy group appears :-(

Comment: Because there are two capture groups in the regular expression.

Comment: you mean like, the capturing process has some kind of "precedence" over the OR condition?

Comment: Yes. The OR condition does not matter. You are going to see tuples with a number of elements equal to the total number of capture groups.

Comment: This is great answer. A simple observation makes the regex so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use this code in Python with lookaheads:

```
>>> s = "id_john, num847, id_000, num___"
>>> print re.findall(r'(?:id_(?=[a-z]+\b)|num(?=\d+\b))([a-z\d]+)', s)
['john', '847']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `id_(?=[a-z]+\b)`: Match `id_` with a lookahead assertion to make sure we have `[a-z]+` characters ahead followed by word boundary
  - `|`: OR
  - `num(?=\d+\b)`)([a-z\d]+`: Match`num` with a lookahead assertion to make sure we have digits ahead followed by word boundary
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `([a-z\d]+)`: Match 1+ characters with lowercase letters or digits