# Regex OR results in two separate groups, how do I make capture it as a single group?

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I'm trying to capture the username for the following input string in GoLang regex, I expected `anonymous` and `prettygurl91` to be in a single group, but it wasn't the case for the following pattern.

Input:

```
[Twitter] An anonymous user has posted a photo on 03-24-2024!
[Twitter] User prettygurl91 has posted a video on 03-25-2024!
```

Pattern:

```
^\[Twitter\] (?:User (.*?)|An (anonymous) user) has posted a (.*) on (.*)\!
```

Resulting groups:

Resulting group for `[Twitter] An anonymous user has posted a photo on 03-24-2024!`

1. Nil
2. anonymous
3. photo
4. 03-24-2024

Resulting group for `[Twitter] User prettygurl91 has posted a video on 03-25-2024!`

1. prettygurl91
2. Nil
3. video
4. 03-25-2024

What is was expecting was the following input strings to be grouped like so

1. prettygurl91 / anonymous
2. photo / video
3. 03-24-2024 / 03-25-2024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with the following regex pattern

```
^\[Twitter\] (?:User|An) (.\S*).* has posted a (.*) on (.*)\!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple capture groups enabled which don't seem to serve any purpose.  And the one capture group you want to use has been turned off.  Try this version:

```
^\[Twitter\] (User \w+|An Anonymous user) has posted a .* on .*!
```

Comment: I needed the other groups for other purposes as stated in the post, I was expecting 3 capture groups.

Anyways, your answer yielded the following for group 1, `An Anonymous user` OR `User prettygurl91`, as said in the post, I need group 1 to be `prettygurl91` OR `anonymous`

Comment: Then you can easily map `An Anonymous user` => `Anonymous` and `User prettygurl91` => `prettygurl91` from your code.

Comment: I would have done that if it's possible to touch other parts of the code, what is allowed is to provide a regex pattern to yield 3 groups, 1st group containing the username or "anonymous" and the other 2 for other purposes, I'm not able to insert other lines of codes.

Comment: i edited the post for clarification

Comment: I don't see any direct way to do this with regex.  Some Go coding logic will need to be involved.

Comment: I was trying to adjust the regex like what was provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542531/return-only-one-group-with-or-condition-in-regex or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144074/regex-combine-capturing-group-with-or-condition but i couldnt get it to work